# nodeJS - cant understand the behavior of the code

Tags: event-loop, single-threaded

```
function placeOrder(orderNo) {
console.log("Order is: " + orderNo);

setTimeout(deliver(orderNo),5000);
}

function deliver(orderNo) {
    console.log("Item is delivered with Order No.- " + orderNo);
}

placeOrder(1);
placeOrder(2);
placeOrder(3);
placeOrder(4);
placeOrder(5);
placeOrder(6);
```

The above code is a nodejs code whose output should be:

```
order No:1
order No:2
order No:3
order No:4
order No:5
order No:6
Item is delivered with order No.- 1
Item is delivered with order No.- 2
Item is delivered with order No.- 3
Item is delivered with order No.- 4
Item is delivered with order No.- 5
Item is delivered with order No.- 6
```

But i am getting an output like this:

```
order No:1
Item is delivered with order No.- 1
order No:2
Item is delivered with order No.- 2
order No:3
Item is delivered with order No.- 3
order No:4
Item is delivered with order No.- 4
order No:5
Item is delivered with order No.- 5
order No:6
Item is delivered with order No.- 6
```

I am going wrong somewhere in my concept of single thread and asynchronous callbacks. Please someone explain me how the code is working.

Comment: Change to; setTimeout("deliver("+orderNo+");",5000);

Comment: also, please indent your code ;)

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
setTimeout(deliver(orderNo),5000);
}
```

with:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    deliver(orderNo); 
}, 5000);
```

The first parameter of the `setTimeout` function is a function pointer. In your code you were passing the result of the `deliver(orderNo)` call which is just some `void` parameter. Now you can get rid of the `console.log` inside your `placeOrder` function.

Answer (score 2):

You use wrong `setTimeout` signature definition

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, [delay, param1, param2, ...]);
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(code, [delay]);
```

Hence, your code should be:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  deliver(orderNo);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

This is a syntax issue. You are passing in the wrong argument *type* to `setTimeout`.

Change this:

```
setTimeout(deliver(orderNo),5000);
```

to this:

```
setTimeout(deliver, 5000, orderNo);
```

Be wary that this syntax does not work in IE 9 or below.

## Explanation

If you look at the documentation for [setTimeout on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), you will see that the first argument is either a `Function` or a `String` consisting of JavaScript code. In your case, you are trying to pass in a function which accepts this syntax:

```
setTimeout(func, [delay, param1, param2, ...]);
```

Where `param1, param2, ...` are the arguments for your function, `func`. What you are doing is passing in the *value returned by the function* rather than *the function itself*.

Since you are passing a value, `setTimeout` does not execute as expected. The reason you are still getting an output from `deliver` is because it is actually being executed at runtime rather than by `setTimeout`. It's almost the same thing as calling `deliver` by itself.

### Functions as Arguments

Remember that functions are [First-Class Citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) in JavaScript, which means they can be passed into function as arguments.

## Bonus

There are a few alternative syntaxes you can use.

### String

As `pokeybit` mentioned in the comments:

```
setTimeout("deliver("+orderNo+");",5000);
```

Which allows you to use the function and it's parameters at once. However, this is an uglier syntax due to the string concatenation.

### Anonymous Function

Use setTimeout with an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Item is delivered with Order No.- " + orderNo);
}, 5000);
```

This is arguably the most common and safest syntax.

### Function that returns an anonymous function

You can keep:

```
setTimeout(deliver(orderNo),5000);
```

If you define `deliver` as a function that returns a `Function`:

```
function deliver(orderNo) {
  return function() {
    console.log("Item is delivered with Order No.- " + orderNo);
  }
}
```

Since this value returns a function, it is the proper type for `setTimeout`.

Comment: No problem. We've all fallen for the `setTimeout` gotcha at one point or another.